# Javascript Mobile Environment

Tags: javascript, mobile

From the script, on the mobile browser, how can I reliably know if the 
onload event has been fired, but if I have no ability to register it.
The problem is the J/S code can be executed before or after the onload 
the event has been fired, and the script has no way to latching on to it 
(if it latches on to onload, and it never comes because it already 
happened, the rest of the code won't execute)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but what I'm thinking you're asking..

You can just do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onLoad(){
        console.log("loaded");
    }
</script>
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Comment: some of the code is injected by our customer prior to onload event firing, I am looking for a DOM event listener (which may not exist or be possible) to monitor executed code programmatically, like firebug without having to be an extension.

Comment: I love how I get a vote down - yet, no else has even attempted to answer this.